# Заменить текст div в WebBrowser на VB.NET

Tags: html, .net, webbrowser, vb.net, basic

Всем привет. Пишу прогу на `Vb.net`(клиент для вк). Нужно заменить текст элемента `div` на странице входа в VK мобильной версии.
Нужно заменить текст `"Мобильная версия поможет Вам оставаться ВКонтакте, даже если Вы далеко от компьютера."` на, например `"Тест12345"`. Жду помощи :)

Answer (score 0):

"Жду помощи :)" - Эээх, а самостоятельно совсем ничего?

Для начала поиск и чтение:
[WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) , [WebBrowser.Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx), [HtmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx), [ObjectForScripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx)

Далее ответ на Ваш вопрос:

код

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        'WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://...")
        ' html  файл для примера, Вы же будете использовать адрес сайта
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = IO.File.OpenText("div.html").ReadToEnd
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        divs(0).InnerHtml = "12345"

        Dim div = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myID")
        div.InnerHtml = "67890"

    End Sub
End Class
```

файл примера div.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () { 
                calljs("webpage onload");
            };          
            function calljs(msg){
            // вызов vb метода
                window.external.log(msg);
                return "меседж из js";
            };
            function setDiv(msg){
                document.getElementById('myID2').innerHTML = msg;
                document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = 'qwerty';
                document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[1].innerHTML = 'QWERTY';
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div >Мобильная версия поможет Вам оставаться ВКонтакте, даже если Вы далеко от компьютера.</div>
        <div id='myID'>Мобильная версия поможет Вам оставаться ВКонтакте, даже если Вы далеко от компьютера.</div>
        <div id='myID2'>Мобильная версия поможет Вам оставаться ВКонтакте, даже если Вы далеко от компьютера.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Исходя из Вашего вопроса, в vb.net скорей всего Вы новичок. Соответственно, могу предложить
перенести функционал, связанный с web, в более привычную среду - Web Browser.

код

```vb
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)>
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ' указываем обьект помеченный ComVisibleAttribute 
        'который будет виден в js и доступен через window.external
        WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = Me
        'WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://...")
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = IO.File.OpenText("div.html").ReadToEnd
    End Sub

    Public Sub log(txt As Object)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(txt + vbNewLine)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' значение div-ов
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("setDiv", New Object() {"новое значение div-а"})
        ' 
        Dim ret = WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", New Object() {5 * 5})
        log("Результат: " + ret.ToString())
        '
        ret = WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("calljs", New Object() {"vb.net message."})
        log(ret.ToString())
        ' инжектим свой скрипт и вызываем из него функцию
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", New Object() {"function test(arg){alert(arg.toString());};", "JavaScript"})
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test", New Object() {100})
    End Sub    
End Class
```

При написании кода будут ошибки, будут-будут, еще как будут...
Особенно при копировании готовых, не кросплатформенных решений, с интернета. В помощь F12 в IE.

А можно для начала и простенький костыль соорудить.

```vb
    ...

    ' чисто для удобства, вспомогательный функционал
    Dim debugjs As String =
        <code>
            var debugjs = true;

            var log = function (text) {
                window.external.log('web message: ' + text);
            };
            window.alert = function (s) {
                window.external.log(s);
            };
            window.confirm = function (s) {
                window.external.log(s);
            };
            window.onerror = function (message, url, line) {
                window.external.log('ERROR: ' + message + '\n Line: ' + line + '\n URL: ' + url + '\n');
                return true;
            };
            log("loaded debug.js");
        </code>

    Private Sub WB_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        ' инжектим вспомогательный функционал
        If WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", New Object() {"typeof window['debugjs']"}) = "undefined" Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", New Object() {debugjs, "JavaScript"})
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

В такой способ мы избавимся от навязчивых информационных окон (alert-ов, erroro-ов и т.п.), которые будут тихо печататся в нашу программу.
Впрочем много чего вспомогательного(заранее работоспособного) можно сюда добавить.

Пару строчек для примера

```vb
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", New Object() {"function testerror(arg){alert(arg.toString());};", "JavaScript"})
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("testerror", New Object() {100})

' а так ошибка
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", New Object() {"function testerror(arg){alert(arg);};", "JavaScript"})
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("testerror", New Object() {100})

'
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", New Object() {"function testerror(){return qwerty};", "JavaScript"})
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("testerror")
'
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", New Object() {"function testerror(){var i = 1 return i;};", "JavaScript"})
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("testerror")
```

Вывод:

```
ERROR: Приведение строки "
" к типу "Double" является недопустимым.
 Line: 8
 URL:    
ERROR: "qwerty" не определено
 Line: 1
 URL:    
ERROR: Предполагается наличие ';'
 Line: 1
 URL:
```

Ой, что-то запечатался я...